# Whitelist for Microsoft bot connector service

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

In order to make my bot as secure as possible, I'd like to disallow any inbound traffic unless it's coming from the MS bot connector. Is there a whitelist of its ips/domains somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need ips/domains, because microsoft bot connector sdk [has security functionality built in](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/connectormisc.html).

Just keep in mind that each your api controller should have `[BotAuthentication]` attribute, and you should use https protocol.

`[BotAuthentication]` attribute validates each request using `MicrosoftAppId Password: MicrosoftAppPassword` which you define in your `web.config` file and thus only bot connector can hit your apis, everyone else will get unauthorized result.

Comment: The connector authentication will not be good enough for my purposes as IIS itself (or w/e server you use) can be attacked. A whitelist is still ideal.